# Javascript - async await not wait until function is done?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I was learning javascript with async and await and tried some example on my own, but it seems when calling the async function (func1) from another function (func2), func2 does not wait for func1 to complete its process and it jumps over and continue executing...is there something wrong with my code or should I also turn func2 into async and call func1 with await? If so, does that mean all functions that will involve an async-await method will need to become async as well?
here is my original code

```
// func1
const func1 = async() => {
   try {
     await putCallToServer(...);
     return 1;     // it returns as a promise
   } catch(ex) {
     return 2;
   }
}

// func2
const func2 = () => {
   let result = 0;
   result = func1(); // should I turn it into await func1()??
   console.log(result);  // log contains '0' instead of '1' or '2'
   return result;    // return as Promise but value inside is 0
}
```

And what if I have a func3 which would call func2, should I turn func3 into async-await as well?

Comment: Yes, you need `await func1()`. Which means you have to make `func2` async.

Comment: The alternative is using promises or callbacks. `async` and `await` are just syntactic sugar on promises.

Comment: Shouldn't `const` in `const result = 0` be `let`? A constant should be defined, but not re-assigned.

Comment: If you don't want to change all your functions into async functions. Consider not calling an async in `func2`, but rather pass the resolved result of `func1` to `func2` as a parameter. `func1().then(func2)` Which would allow you to define `func2` as `const func2 = result => {console.log(result); return result;}`

Comment: ALL `await` does is suspend the execution of the current function and then IMMEDIATELY return a promise back to the caller.  The caller HAS to do something with that promise to know when the function is actually done.  If the caller is not also awaiting the returned promise or not using `.then()` to know when it's done, then the caller will never know when its done and will never "wait" for anything.  This is how `async/await` works.  `await` suspends execution of the function and immediately returns a promise back to the caller.  `await` does not pause the entire interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, both functions must be async in order to use await. This can be seen below in the code snippet. (since i do not wish to call an actual server in an example, I am throwing in putCallToServer(). This is returning the result of 2.

I also changed result to be a let variable since you were trying to mut a const which is not allowed.

```js
async function putCallToServer() {
 throw "too lazy to make a real error"
}
// func1
const func1 = async() => {
   try {
     await putCallToServer();
     return 1;     // it returns as a promise
   } catch(ex) {
     return 2;
   }
}

// func2
const func2 = async() => {
   let result = 0;
   result = await func1(); // should I turn it into await func1()??
   console.log(result);  // log contains '0' instead of '1' or '2'
   return result;    // return as Promise but value inside is 0
}
func2()
```

Comment: Thank you! So going forward, if I have a func3 which would be calling func2, I need to make func3 as async and call func2 using await inside as well?

Comment: Yes. In order to use await, BOTH the function you are calling AND the function you are making the call from need to be async.

Comment: Thanks! Here I see when you call `fun2` , you just do `fun2`, not `await fun2`, I've seen it been using like this but why is that? Is it because the `caller` here is windows?

Comment: Or something like `(async() => await func2())()` ?