# javascript async await not waiting

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

Here are the functions I have.

```
async function check_saved_url() {
  $.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {
    current_ip = response.ip;
    location_here = response.country;
    
    var ajax_get_url_prefix = base_url + 'getDomain.php?ip=';
    var key_ip = current_ip + '@@@' + domain_permanent;
    var url = ajax_get_url_prefix + key_ip;
    
    $.get(url, function(data, status) {
      console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      if (data.includes('0 results')) {
        return 'unknown';
      } else {
        return data;
      }
    });
  }, "jsonp");
}

const func1 = async() => {
  return await check_saved_url();
}

const func2 = async() => {
  let domain_preference = '';
  domain_preference = await func1();
  console.log("domain_preference: ",domain_preference);
}
func2();
```

This method is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63256040/12992521).

As you can see, there are two jquery ajax to get data from server.

The problem is, the `func1` and `func2` never waits until `check_saved_url` returns value.

This is what I see in console.

[image]

The top red line is the output of `func2`, which must wait until `check_saved_url` runs, whose result is the following 2 circles.

I am not sure why this persists to happen and hours of copying answers from everywhere didn't help me.

Comment: I see no awaits inside of check_saved_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from `check_saved_url`. Inside of the Promise, you then need to use `resolve` to replace `return`. You can also use `reject(new Error("error"))` if there was an error.

```js
async function check_saved_url() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {
      current_ip = response.ip;
      location_here = response.country;

      var ajax_get_url_prefix = base_url + 'getDomain.php?ip=';
      var key_ip = current_ip + '@@@' + domain_permanent;
      var url = ajax_get_url_prefix + key_ip;

      $.get(url, function(data, status) {
        console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        if (data.includes('0 results')) {
          // Instead of return, use resolve()
          //return 'unknown'; 
          resolve('unknown');
          // You can also pass an error with `reject(new Error("error"))`
        } else {
          // Instead of return, use resolve()
          //return data; 
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    }, "jsonp");
  });
}

const func1 = async() => {
  return await check_saved_url();
}

const func2 = async() => {
  let domain_preference = '';
  domain_preference = await func1();
  console.log("domain_preference: ",domain_preference);
}
func2();
```

You can read more about promises on [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: Thanks, @Rojo! I am actually new to this async-await. I have a question, then. Is there a javascript method that originally returns promise? I mean natively async functions? I see many examples of async functions that uses normal return.

Comment: @Nikita functions that aren't using promises are instead using `await`. They are calling `await` on awaitable functions that essentially use promises or are natively awaitable. In your case, you are trying to await `$.get()`. I'm pretty sure `$.get()` uses native JS functions that are not awaitable. Instead, they have events and listeners. With onload events, you need to use promises.

Comment: @Nikita `async` functions always return promises (even though they look like they don't).

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to develop your understanding of [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and how [async JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) works a little.

If you *have* to use jQuery, you could promisify the jQuery [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/)  method (which appears to use a very old version of the promise API?), and then use that with modern JS constructs like `async`/`await`.

```js
const pGet = (url, dataType = 'jsonp') => 
  new Promise((success, error) => $.ajax({url, dataType, success, error}))
   
const IP_URL = 'https://ipinfo.io/json'
const PREFERENCE_URL_PREFIX = 'https://www.example.com/getDomain.php?ip='

const go = async () => {
  try {
    const { ip } = await pGet(IP_URL)
    const preference = await pGet(`${PREFERENCE_URL_PREFIX}${ip}`)
    //do something with the preference
  } catch(err) {
    // handle errors
  }
}

go()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't have to use jQuery, I'd avoid it and use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) provided by modern host environments.

```js
const IP_URL = 'https://ipinfo.io/json'
const PREFERENCE_URL_PREFIX = 'https://www.example.com/getDomain.php?ip='

const go = async () => {
  try {
    const { ip } = await (await fetch(IP_URL)).json()
    const preference = await fetch(`${PREFERENCE_URL_PREFIX}${ip}`)
    //do something with the preference
  } catch(err) {
    // handle errors
  }
}

go()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no promise returned by `check_saved_url` nor is $.get returning a promise. You need to wrap it all in a promise

```
async function check_saved_url() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {
            current_ip = response.ip;
            location_here = response.country;

            var ajax_get_url_prefix = base_url + 'getDomain.php?ip=';
            var key_ip = current_ip + '@@@' + domain_permanent;
            var url = ajax_get_url_prefix + key_ip;

            $.get(url, function(data, status) {
                console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                if (data.includes('0 results')) {
                    resolve('unknown');
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            })
                .fail(reject);
        }, "jsonp")
            .fail(reject);
    })
}
```

#### Clean the code

To have a cleaner and reusable code you can wrap `$.get` in a `Promise`

```
async function async_get(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const jqxhr = $.get(url);
        jqxhr.done(() => resolve({ json: jqxhr.responseJSON, status: jqxhr.status }));
        jqxhr.fail(() => reject(jqxhr));
    })
}

async function check_saved_url() {
    const { json: response } = await async_get("https://ipinfo.io/json");
    current_ip = response.ip;
    location_here = response.country;
    var ajax_get_url_prefix = base_url + 'getDomain.php?ip=';
    var key_ip = current_ip + '@@@' + domain_permanent;
    var url = ajax_get_url_prefix + key_ip;

    const { json: data, status } = await $.get(url);
    console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    return data.includes('0 results') ? 'unknown' : data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `check_saved_url` does not return a promise - this is why `await` is not working for it.

The solution would be to return a promise in `check_saved_url`.

Suppose I have a function `create_promise` which I want to await (this mimics your 'get' request):

```js
function create_promise() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Done!"), 500);
  });
}


const func1 = async() => {
  const result = await create_promise();
  return result + " <- result";
};

func1().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use fetch API check_saved_url(). It return promise. You can read more about it here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Code will go like this :

```
async function check_saved_url() {
    let connect = await fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json")
    let response = await connect.json()
    current_ip = response.ip;
    location_here = response.country;
    
    var ajax_get_url_prefix = base_url + 'getDomain.php?ip=';
    var key_ip = current_ip + '@@@' + domain_permanent;
    var url = ajax_get_url_prefix + key_ip;
      
    //   $.get(url, function(data, status) {
    //     console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    //     if (data.includes('0 results')) {
    //       return 'unknown';
    //     } else {
    //       return data;
    //     }
    //   });
    // }, "jsonp");
  }
```